# adding a table attribute as an paramater in sql query?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

i want to calculate tax from already made table through stored procedure

```
 name,   ssn,      salary
'harsh', '49892', '40000'
'nitin', '48539', '55000'
'param', '48999', '75000'
'kd',    '84998', '120000'
```

i want to use parametrized way of doing it if not possible then tell some other way

```
/*CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `compute tax`(out tax varchar(10), in salary double)*/
```

something like this that can take value of salary into parameters and then can create a table using if else statements

Comment: can you elaborate your question how doy ou want to cqalculate your taxes? how do you want the result

Comment: Where do you get tax rates from? Why do you think you need a procedure (I don't think you do)?NB mysql does not have table variables...